# Load dynamic content on compile in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, compilation

I want to load the content of a table from one of my oracle databases in the moment of compilation. The content could be compiled in what ever way into the assembly (txt, csv, datatable, etc.).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with oracle, but it is obviously possible. I'll post some code for using sql server.

```
 public DataSet OrderDetails()
    {
        DataSet GetOrderDetails = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand CustDetails = new SqlCommand();                        
        CustDetails.CommandText = "Your SQl Command";
        CustDetails.CommandType = CommandType.Text          
        CustDetails.Connection = TSConnection.GetConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter mySQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(CustDetails);
        mySQLDataAdapter.Fill(GetOrderDetails);            
        return GetOrderDetails;                    
    }
```

You can assign this data to an asp.net gridview control. There is plenty of documentation on how to do this but it will be something like this.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
```

Then your c# code behind you have to grab that data and post it to the view

```
 GridView1.DataSource =  OrderDetails()
 GridView1.DataBind();
```